# Sorting and merging two tensors with tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tensorflow, merge

I have two tensors, A and B, which are Nx3 each. I also have a boolean tensor C = Nx1. I want to use this boolean to merge A and B following the values of C. For example:

```
A = [[ a1, a2, a3],
     [ a4, a5, a6],
     [ a7, a8, a9]]

B = [[ b1, b2, b3],
     [ b4, b5, b6],
     [ b7, b8, b9]]

C = [True, True, False]
```

What I want is to obtain something like this:

```
D = [[[ a1, a2, a3],
      [ b1, b2, b3]],

     [[ a4, a5, a6],
      [ b4, b5, b6]],

     [[ b7, b8, b9],
      [ a7, a8, a9]]]
```

As you can see, both tensors have been merged and the order of which row goes first is determined by the values of C.

Two `Nx3` tensors A and B are merged into one `D = Nx2x3` tensor by merging the rows of the original tensors. The order in which they are added to the `Nx2x3` tensor depends on the boolean tensor C, i.e.

> if C[i] = True, D[i,0,:] = A[i,:] and D[i, 1, :] = B[i, :]. If C[i] = False, then D[i, 0, :] = B[i, :] and D[i, 1, :] = A[i, :]

I'm sure there's a simple approach to this but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Could you explain this further ?

Comment: I'm truing to merge the two Nx3 tensors A and B into one D = Nx2x3 tensor by mergin the rows of the original tensors. The order in which they are added to the Nx2x3 tensor depends on the boolean tensor C, i.e. if C[i] = True, D[i,0,:] = A[i,:] and D[i, 1, :] = B[i, :]. If C[i] = False, then D[i, 0, :] =  B[i, :] and D[i, 1, :]  = A[i, :]

Comment: Add your details too for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, although it might not be an efficient one. In case anyone else has the same problem, the way I got it to work is as follows (Using the same A, B, C and D as above):

```
row_num = tf.cast(tf.reshape(tf.range(A.shape[0]), [-1, 1]), tf.int64)
AB = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(A, 1), tf.expand_dims(B, 1)], axis=1)
filt_top = tf.reshape(tf.cast(C, tf.int64), [-1, 1])
filt_bottom = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.logical_not(C), tf.int64), [-1, 1])
filt = tf.concat([row_num, filt_top, filt_bottom], axis=1)
D_top = tf.map_fn(lambda x: AB[x[0], x[1], :], filt, dtype=tf.float32)
D_bottom = tf.map_fn(lambda x: AB[x[0], x[2], :], filt, dtype=tf.float32)
D = tf.concat([D_top, D_bottom], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A`, `B` and `C` are Numpy's array, you can merge them in this way by using Numpy's masking indexing technology:

```
D = np.zeros((N,2,3))
D[C,0,:] = A[C]
D[~C,0,:] = B[~C]
D[~C,1,:] = A[~C]
D[C,1,:] = B[C]
```

In fact, `C` do not have to be a Numpy's array. A list is okay to be the indexing of an array in Python.